# Tengo 4 botones en una pantalla, cada uno lanza un Activity diferente pero solo me funciona uno

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy programando una app para un proyecto, tengo una pantalla con 4 botones (menu) cada boton me manda a un nuevo Activity pero solo me funciona el boton que me manda al activity de perfil.

```
package com.example.slash.serviceconect;
```

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by slash on 25/02/2018.
 */

public class menuduenoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
Button eventos, irstock, empleados, perfil;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menudueno);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    perfil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.perfil);
    perfil.setOnClickListener(this);
    irstock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botstock);
    irstock.setOnClickListener(this);
    eventos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botevento);
    eventos.setOnClickListener(this);
    empleados = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botempleado);
    empleados.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.perfil:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, perfilActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.botstock:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, stockActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.botevento:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, eventosActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.botempleado:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, empleadosActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Esta es el mensaje de la consola:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.slash.serviceconect, PID: 7477
              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.slash.serviceconect/com.example.slash.serviceconect.stockActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1895)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1589)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4229)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4530)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4498)
                  at com.example.slash.serviceconect.menuduenoActivity.onClick(menuduenoActivity.java:81)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

La verdad que necesito una solucion pues este error no me deja continuar con mi proyecto, he intentado programando diferentes formas de desplazarme entre activity's.

Comment: Hola Emmanuel, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: todas las Activities deben ser declaradas en el manifest, siendo la Launcher la activity menuduenoActivity

Answer (score 1):

Buenas noches Emmanuel,

El error que se detalla indica que no encuentra el Activity definido en tu código, por lo que te recomiendo que mires en tu archivo AndroidManifest.XML si están detallados esos activities.

En caso de que sí existan, podrías mirar que las etiquetas se encuentran dentro de la etiqueta padre APPLICATION.

Ejemplo:

```
    <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

       <activity  
          android:name=".Compte"  
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

       <activity
             android:name=".Menu" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >

             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>

       </activity>

    </application>
```

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que es eso, más concretamente la falta de declaración de la clase `stockActivity`.

Comment: Que tal, si tengo todos las clases en el manifest los tenia de esta forma: " <activity android:name=".stockActivity">", lo que hice fue agregarle como a tu codigo el android:screenOrientation y esto me hizo funcionara el boton de stock pero no los otros dos faltantes. ¿Que es el android:label=?

Comment: Encontre la solucion, le quite el fondo de pantalla a los activitys.xml colocando android:background="@color/colorAccent" con el atributo "color" si se puede llamar asi en vez de buscar el archivo de imagen que diseñe para el fondo, sabras cual el es problema aqui? quizas el tipo de imagen o el hecho de que los hice el doble de su tamaño para tener una buena resolucion, los achivos estan hechos en formato png.

Answer (score 0):

Me sirvio poner el atributo

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

a todos los botones

y...
Cambiar

```
name.setOnClickListener(this);
```

por

```
name.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
```

Answer (score -1):

En este caso el mensaje de error es:

> Process: com.example.slash.serviceconect, PID: 7477
>                 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.example.slash.serviceconect/com.example.slash.serviceconect.stockActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Que traduciéndolo a español sería:

> Proceso: com.example.slash.serviceconect, PID: 7477
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: no **se puede encontrar la clase de actividad explícita**
>   {com.example.slash.serviceconect / com.example.slash.serviceconect.stockActivity};
>   **¿has declarado esta actividad en tu AndroidManifest.xml?**

Todas las `Activity` que son usadas en tu proyecto deben ser declaradas dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, dentro de `<application>` :

```
 ...
 ...
       <activity android:name=".perfilActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".stockActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".eventosActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".empleadosActivity"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.